# To transfer attributes from a polygon feature class (that contains line feature ) to the line feature class using python script

Tags: gis, arcgis

Has anyone tried to trasfer attributes from a polygon feature class to a line feature class using python script. I have done it with Spatialjoin and Identity, but the output is often another feature class-. I need to get polygon attributes and transfer them to the line feature class. Please help...

Answer (score 1):

From your statement, i think you have the ArcGIS Desktop..

Identify the common id between the poly and line feature.

then do join based on the common id. have the line feature as input and polygon as join features.

Verify the join, and then export the line feature.. it will create a new line feature with all attributes from polygon..

After you practice these steps, you can easily find the python codes.